# NumberFormatException in Java for a string that is a number

Tags: java, udp, numberformatexception

I am implementing socket programming using Java. I get this error.

My code is:

```
public class UDPServer  {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
    byte[] num1b = new byte[1024];      
    String num1String;
    DatagramPacket recievePacket;
    String sndmsg;
    int port;
    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9676);
    System.out.println("UDP Server running");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    while(true) {
        recievePacket = new DatagramPacket(num1b, num1b.length);
        serverSocket.receive(recievePacket);
        num1String = new String(recievePacket.getData());
        System.out.println(num1String);
        System.out.println(num1String.length());
         int numbers2=Integer.parseInt(num1String);
```

I run my UDP client:

```
Enter number 1 :2
Enter number 2 :5
Enter number 3 :4
Enter number 4 :3
Enter number 5 :1
Select Protocol: 
1.UDP
2.TCP
1
Data sent to server
```

My Server Shows this:

```
$ java UDPServer 
UDP Server running
waiting for data from client 
2
1024
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at UDPServer.main(UDPServer.java:49)
$
```

What is causing this error? Why is my string 2 not getting converted?

Comment: Show us the whole code and point the line where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @ I edited my post. Please check?

Comment: You cut the code in the middle of the `while` loop. You should post all the code to get accurate answer. Where is the exception being thrown ? Whats the output of the console ? I want to know what `System.out.println(num1String)` prints.

Comment: That is where my code stopped working! The string gets printed. Like I said at the beginning of my post, the 6 that gets printed is my string. But the parsing isn't happening.

Comment: I need to know **how** it gets printed. Also, what is the value of `num1String.length();`? My guess is that very is some non printable character mixed with the `String` that makes the parsing fails.

Comment: @ortis I edited my post. It shows a length of 1024

Comment: That means that the way you are sending data is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63792/discussion-between-divinediu-and-ortis).

Comment: Sorry, cant access chat right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an issue with your client code. However, a simple workaround would be to take the first character of `num1String`:

```
int numbers2=Integer.parseInt(num1String.substring(0, 1));
```

Comment: Will this take care of double digit numbers?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
num1String = new String(recievePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());
```

When you receive a packet from the server, `receivePacket.getLength()` will give you the number of bytes received. The remaining bytes in the array will be unchanged as they aren't part of the last received packet, and most of them will most likely be 0. If you include those in your `String`, it will contain a lot of irrelevant characters at the end, mostly `null`-characters (depending on the remaining bytes and the default charset). And some IDE's and/or platforms may not print the whole `String` if it contains `null`-characters.