# Why is the Integer.parseInt not working in my java code?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, parseint

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args ) throws IOException{
    String seconds = " ";

     Scanner sc2 = null;
        try {
            sc2 = new Scanner(new File("/Users/mohammadmuntasir/Downloads/customersfile.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }

        boolean first = true;
        while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
                Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());    
            while (s2.hasNext()) {
                String s = s2.next();
                if (first == true){
                    seconds = s;
                    first = false;
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(seconds)); // causes ERROR?

     }
 }
```

I am trying to read a number from a text file which is in the first line by itself. I made an integer called seconds that will take in the first number and will be parsed into an integer. But I always get a numbers exception error and that I can't parse it. When I display s as a string, it displays a number without spaces next to it. Can anyone explain why this happens?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "300" 
  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatE‌xception.java:65) 
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580) 
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) 
  at MainProgram.main(MainProgram.java:29)
```

Comment: The exception is NumberFormatException ?

Comment: May be check `String seconds = " ";`, you are trying to parse space into int

Comment: *But I always get a numbers exception error*

Comment: If your while loop stuff does not entered into then `seconds` will remain as `" "` which of course is not a number.  Try debugging it

Comment: a tiny hint: the Exception (Stacktrace) actually tells you EXACTLY what you are trying to parse. From there on it should be rather trivial to identify WHY this doesn´t work (well if so it´s not a number you´re trying to parse)

Comment: Put breakpoint on the `System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(seconds));` line and see what value does `seconds` hold.

Comment: @Rupesh nah that isnt it. when i system.out.print(seconds), it prints 300 (which is my first number)

Comment: Your string may be empty or you string may contain space. So use trim & then parse.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: I doubt that it has spaces. So, please trim it and then parse.

Comment: @aUserHimself, Sorry for my limited knowledge of java, but how do I find the full stack trace?

Comment: @Dankmemer it´s written inside the console whenever you execute it.

Comment: Maybe you try to use s2.nextInt() instead of s2.next(). It returns an int instead of a string.

Comment: Can you also post the content of `customersfile.txt`?

Comment: This is very important but probably not at the root of this problem: Use [Scanner(File source, String charsetName))](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.File-java.lang.String-) instead of the one that uses the default character set. The text file was written with a specific character encoding. You must read it with that. Default varies and is rarely appropriate. For this case, if we are looking at the bytes in the text file, we need to know the encoding because Scanner will map them to the UTF-16 encoding of the Unicode character set that Java uses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the exception message is really this:

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "300"
```

then we are starting to get into really obscure causes.

- It could be a problem with homoglyphs; i.e. Unicode characters that *look like* one character but are actually different characters.
- It could be a non-printing character.  For example an ASCII NUL ... or a Unicode BOM ([Byte Order Marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) character.

I can think of three ways to diagnose this:

1. Run your code in a debugger and set a breakpoint on the parseInt method.  Then look at the String object that you are trying to parse, checking its length (say N) and the first N `char` values in the character array.
2. Use a file tool to examine the file as bytes.  (On UNIX / Linux / MacOSX, use the `od` command.)
3. Add some code to get the string as an array of characters.  For each array entry, cast the `char` to an `int` and print the resulting number.

All three ways should tell you exactly what the characters in the string are, and that should explain why `parseInt` thinks they are wrong.

---

<sup>Another possibility is that you copied the exception message incorrectly.  The stacktrace was a bit mangled by the time you got it into the Question ...</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your input file with a hex-editor. It might start with some "strange" hex codes called [Byte Order Markers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). This would explain why the Exception is so misleading becaus BOMs won't be shown on the console.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this, I had the same probleme , Integer.ParseInt(String) didn't work for me, I added .trim() and it works perfectly:

```
int id_of_command;
        try {
             id_of_command = Integer.parseInt(id_of_Commands_str.trim());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
             id_of_command = 0;
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to parse space then it would cause an issue. Please check what value of `seconds` you are trying to parse.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:22)
```

---

Additionally try catching the exception and printing the value which is causing it. Something like this:

```
try{
      System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(seconds));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("String value: '" + seconds + "'");
    }
```

---

Can you update the question with stack-trace. Not sure what are the contents in your file.

Comment: 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "300"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at MainProgram.main(MainProgram.java:29)'

Comment: @Dankmemer edit it into the question so people are able to read it (it´s pretty unreadable in the comment section)

Comment: Could be homoglyphs

Comment: @StephenC: Then would be interested to see what's there in that file.

Comment: Could also be non-printing characters ... of various kinds.

Comment: going to throw [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609613/numberformatexception-in-java-for-a-string-that-is-a-number) in, might this help? it could also help to check `seconds.length` against the visible length

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy: had this thought but stack trace wraps the String to be parsed in double quotes. E.g "300" as oppose to "300 ". Yes but worth looking at the post you just mentioend.

Comment: @Rupesh yeah i know, the link also shows the same exception for an input `"2"`, there might be a correlation here (at least i can´t recreate the error without the exact file contents)

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure you are reading an integer, you can use seconds.trim() to trim any spaces and parse it.

Comment: I am sure seconds is an integer. And seconds.trim() doesnt help :/

Comment: @Dankmemer - well we are equally sure that you are wrong about that!  However if you were paying attention, you would have seen our **repeated** requests for you to post the **full** stacktrace ... which would clear up any possible doubt as to what you are actually parsing here.

Comment: NumberFormatException is thrown only if seconds does not contain parseable ineteger. Please see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Comment: @OTM This can be better placed  under comments section and not in "Answers" section.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible to append your code with something like this and put out your answer :

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : seconds.toCharArray())
    {
        sb.append((int)c).append(",");
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

Answer (score -2):

Your string can be empty or you string may contain space. So use trim & then parse.